# No bottom quark in parton distribution function

Tags: particle-physics

> CTEQ6M Parton Distribution:
>
> http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Introduction_to_Parton_Distribution_Functions

My understanding is that bottom/top quarks can exist (at least temporarily) as sea quarks in the proton by quark-antiquark pair production from gluons.

At $Q = 2$ $GeV$, the charm density is null below the charm mass threshold $m_c ≈ 1.5$ $GeV$.
At $Q = 100$ $GeV$, bottom quark density is also null, even though a significant portion of the domain is above the bottom mass threshold $m_b ≈ 5$ $GeV$.

Why is this?